# How to set a value for the input in redux form using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, redux-form, ts-jest

I am trying to set a value for one of the field in my reduxform using jest and enzyme like below.

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SignInForm onSubmit={mockButtonSubmit} />
    </Provider>,
  );

 const email_name = wrapper.findWhere(n => n.name() === 'Field'
    && n.prop('name') === 'email');

    const input = email_name.find('input');

    input.node.value = "test";

    input.simulate('change', input);
    wrapper.update();

    console.log('input', email_name.debug());
```

But when i run the test i am getting the error as

```
Property 'node' does not exist on type 'ReactWrapper<HTMLAttributes, any, Component<{}, {}, any>>
```

Versions:

```
"enzyme": "^3.10.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
"jest": "^24.8.0",
```

Comment: There is no property as node in [enzyme library](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html) . That is why `input.node` is getting error. Anyway you not using value any where

Comment: @paragxviii i am testing whether the input value can be changed or not

Comment: If you want to change the value then identify how does your actual code change that value i.e any event then trigger that. Otherwise use `setProps` or `setState` to update the content,